# CSS div stretching to full browser width

Tags: css, html, css-position

The output of this below code DIV #imagemiddle is not stretching till the browser full width, I want the top tool bar has to be fixed and the below div to be `position: relative` and not absolute or fixed.

#### HTML

```
<div id="topbar"></div>
<div id="imagemiddle"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#topbar {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #2D2D2A;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    height: 42px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
#imagemiddle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 40px;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    background-color: "red"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution, you need add `margin:0;` to the body in your css.

```
body{ margin:0;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PEjVx/)**

Comment: Thanks, it works like a breeze, I am a newbie and this really helped me.. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser's default body margin is the problem:

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8uNY/

Consider using a [reset spreadsheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or creating a custom one to avoid cross-browser CSS inconsistencies.

Also, when using words for CSS colors (`red`), don't put them inside quotes.

```
background-color: red;
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. Perfect. I am  a newbie and this tip helped a lot of time. cheers.

Comment: No problem, you can easily debug things like that using DevTools or Firebug. :)

Comment: @Rob Which is exactly why I wrote "or creating a custom one"... Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Shomz He won't need a custom one, either, except to set the body margin to zero (if that's what he wants). Suggesting a css reset when all he needs is a body margin of zero will get a downvote from me every time (and I rarely downvote).

Comment: @Rob Margin zero, padding zero, border zero... and a couple more for a few other elements (you'd have to add those while you're building the page anyway). In my world that's called a custom reset css and we don't get downvoted for that...cheers

Comment: @Shomz Right. You're setting those properties only to have them set a second time elsewhere. But he only needs a zero margin on the body, not all things. I'm not debating what a reset is. I'm disagreeing he needs a reset and whether anyone ever needs a reset.